# Incorporating Structure Fields into a Function as Inputs (in MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, function

I'm using MATLAB (Mapping Toolbox) to create a large number of lines between different countries. Since there are so many lines, I'm trying to do this using object-oriented programming. This is the method I've written:

```
function transline = createlines(transline, Name, base.CapTr.val(a,b), base.EtrOut.val(:,a,b,1), base.EtrOut.val(:,b,a,1), base.EtrIn.val(:,a,b,1), base.EtrIn.val(:,b,a,1), coords(c,2), coords(c,1), coords(d,2), coords(d,1))
```

where base is a struct and I intend to substitute different values for 'a' and 'b'. e.g., `base.CapTr.val(3,4)` and create new objects.

The problem is I can't include `base.CapTr.val(a,b)` and the subsequent entries as inputs to the function because MATLAB declares the '.' to be an unexpected operator.

So, can you please tell me how I can add varying values of `base.CapTr.val(a,b)`, etc. as inputs to the function?

I don't know if I've explained my problem properly, but I hope it's clear.

Thank you.

Comment: if you want a value within a structure as part of a function, then in the function definition, you reference it like this: function transline = createlines(transline, Name, X) and when you call the function, you can do it like this:function transline = createlines(transline, Name, base.CapTr.val(a,b))